# Jersey, using HTML file instead of HTML string

Tags: java, html, jersey

Currently I need to programm a RESTful Webservice in Java and I'm using Grizzly server as my server and I'm using Jersey for the HTML code generation.

This is my Grizzly server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URI baseUri = URI.create("http://localhost:9998");
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(homepage.class);
    final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, resourceConfig);
    System.out.println("Starting grizzly ...");     
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stop Server");
    server.shutdownNow();
}
```

And this is my current homepage code:

```
@Path("")
public class homepage {

@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String sayHelloInHtml() {
    return "<html><body><h2>Hello World</h2></body></html>";
}
}
```

Right now I'm using a string for my HTML code but is their a way to use a HTML file instead?

Also how can I create a button that triggers a Java method on click? I know how to create a button but I don't know how to make the event handler to trigger the Java method on click.

Comment: You can just have your HTML file as a resource and then read it and return it. If you want a button with an event, you will likely have to have javascript in your HTML file that in turn calls your rest API to return something else. This does not sound like a good design decission. Instead, look into java ui frameworks that give you this functionality out of the box, for example vaadin or eclipse RAP or wicket.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. To read and convert the html file into a string was so simple and worked perfect. Also eclipse RAP looks like it has everything I need. I will look into that and see how it works out. Thanks =)

Comment: RAP is quite need. Particularly, you can compile it into a desktop application or web application from the same code. Only thing I believe is that RAP has limited gradle build support (but i might be wrong)